# Open source PostScript interpreter

Tags: interpreter, postscript

I'm looking for a simple PostScript interpreter to read. What open source PostScript interpreters exist?

I know about [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com) of course and also about [xpost](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/). Oh, I've just found [ralpage](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/x11/x.org/R5contrib/ralpage.tar.Z), but it does not compile out of the box in modern compilers.

Comment: There is an excellent write-up of the ralpage interpreter in: http://www.amazon.com/Workstations-Publication-Systems-Rae-Earnshaw/dp/0387965270/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1374079473&sr=8-2&keywords=earnshaw+workstations

Comment: @luserdroog, I know, I had a copy once but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Usenet search turns up one (in assembly): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.sources.amiga/postscript$20interpreter

Comment: The original code is now available at https://info.computerhistory.org/aoc-postscript

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there *are* any others...... Nobody sane would write a PostScript interpreter these days, and most of the old ones have vanished into the mists of history.

Comment: I'd like to see the old ones, if someone knows where to find them.

Comment: I came across a few in Amiga archives, but they're all in assembly.

Comment: @KenS I took a little offense when I first read this; but thinking back, I *did* have some issues back in '08 when I started work on xpost. +1 This is the truth.

Comment: It is such an enormous task (I was told 3-5 man-years) that it really takes some messianic delusions to want to start work on it. What ultimately persuaded me was the fact that I had been dreaming about writing it since 1998. :D So, had I started out a little stupider, I might've been done already by '07??!! I make efforts to keep my messianic dreams in check, but I cannot deny that they're there. And this I fear properly raises the issue of sanity. Though I hope that further facts continue to dispel it. :)

Comment: I'm busy working at one in spare time for over a year (or is it already 2 or 3?) :'(

Comment: People still use lisp, so you could be sane and want to write one.  I actually enjoy programming in postscript. The bit that would be useful to me is just postscript without the graphical operators.  It seems you can do pretty much anything is postscript that you can in lisp.  I probably should learn enough lisp so that I could implement postscript.